# Custom Connect Four game on CodePen using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html5, connect-four

[image]
Can this code be shortened, optimized or remove any unnecessary parts. Just curious if this is the right way to achieve the given result in this CodePen example: [CodePen Connect Four](https://codepen.io/MistaKisthur/pen/YzWMpMN)

Here is my code:

```js
 // Debug & fix this Script..

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
    const displayCurrentPlayer = document.querySelector('#current-player')
    const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid div')
    const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#Reset')
    const result = document.querySelector('#result')


    let currentPlayer = 1

    for(var i = 0, len = squares.length; i < len; i++)
        (function(index){
        // add an onclick to each square in the grid
            squares[i].onclick = function(){
                // if the square below your current square is taken, you can go ontop of it.
                if(squares[index + 7].classList.contains('taken')){
                    if(!squares[index].classList.contains('taken')){
                        if(currentPlayer === 1){
                            squares[index].classList.add('taken')
                            squares[index].classList.add('player-one')
                            // Change the player
                            currentPlayer = 2
                            displayCurrentPlayer.innerHTML = currentPlayer
                            // displayCurrentPlayer.style.background = 'blue';
                        }else if(currentPlayer === 2){
                            squares[index].classList.add('taken')
                            squares[index].classList.add('player-two')
                            // Change the player
                            currentPlayer = 1
                            displayCurrentPlayer.innerHTML = currentPlayer
                            // displayCurrentPlayer.style.backgroundImage = `linear-gradient(-33deg,blue,green)!important`;
                        }
                    }
                } else alert('Cant Go Here')
            }
        resetBtn.addEventListener('mousedown',(e) => {
            if(squares[index + 7].classList.contains('taken')){
                squares[index].classList.remove('taken')
                squares[index].classList.remove('player-one')
                squares[index].classList.remove('player-two')
                displayCurrentPlayer.innerHTML = 1
            }
        });
    })(i)
    //check the board for a win or lose
    function checkBoard() {
        //make const that shows all winning arrays
        const winningArrays = [
        [0, 1, 2, 3], [41, 40, 39, 38], [7, 8, 9, 10], [34, 33, 32, 31], [14, 15, 16, 17], [27, 26, 25, 24], [21, 22, 23, 24],
        [20, 19, 18, 17], [28, 29, 30, 31], [13, 12, 11, 10], [35, 36, 37, 38], [6, 5, 4, 3], [0, 7, 14, 21], [41, 34, 27, 20],
        [1, 8, 15, 22], [40, 33, 26, 19], [2, 9, 16, 23], [39, 32, 25, 18], [3, 10, 17, 24], [38, 31, 24, 17], [4, 11, 18, 25],
        [37, 30, 23, 16], [5, 12, 19, 26], [36, 29, 22, 15], [6, 13, 20, 27], [35, 28, 21, 14], [0, 8, 16, 24], [41, 33, 25, 17],
        [7, 15, 23, 31], [34, 26, 18, 10], [14, 22, 30, 38], [27, 19, 11, 3], [35, 29, 23, 17], [6, 12, 18, 24], [28, 22, 16, 10],
        [13, 19, 25, 31], [21, 15, 9, 3], [20, 26, 32, 38], [36, 30, 24, 18], [5, 11, 17, 23], [37, 31, 25, 19], [4, 10, 16, 22],
        [2, 10, 18, 26], [39, 31, 23, 15], [1, 9, 17, 25], [40, 32, 24, 16], [9, 7, 25, 33], [8, 16, 24, 32], [11, 7, 23, 29],
        [12, 18, 24, 30], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 4, 3, 2], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12, 11, 10, 9], [15, 16, 17, 18], [19, 18, 17, 16],
        [22, 23, 24, 25], [26, 25, 24, 23], [29, 30, 31, 32], [33, 32, 31, 30], [36, 37, 38, 39], [40, 39, 38, 37], [7, 14, 21, 28],
        [8, 15, 22, 29], [9, 16, 23, 30], [10, 17, 24, 31], [11, 18, 25, 32], [12, 19, 26, 33], [13, 20, 27, 34]
        ];
        //now take the 4 values in earch winningArray & plug them into the squares values
        for(let y = 0; y < winningArrays.length; y++) {
            const square1 = squares[winningArrays[y][0]];
            const square2 = squares[winningArrays[y][1]];
            const square3 = squares[winningArrays[y][2]];
            const square4 = squares[winningArrays[y][3]];

            //now check those arrays to see if they all have the class of player-one
            if(square1.classList.contains('player-one') &&
                square2.classList.contains('player-one') &&
                square3.classList.contains('player-one') &&
                square4.classList.contains('player-one')) {
                    //if they do, player-one is passed as the winner
                    result.innerHTML = 'Player one wins!'
                    //remove ability to change result
            }
            //now check to see if they all have the classname player two
            else if (square1.classList.contains('player-two') &&
                square2.classList.contains('player-two') &&
                square3.classList.contains('player-two') &&
                square4.classList.contains('player-two')) {
                    //if they do, player-two is passed as the winner as well as the chip positions
                    result.innerHTML = 'Player two wins!'
            }
        }
    }
    //add an event listener to each square that will trigger the checkBoard function on click
    squares.forEach(square => square.addEventListener('click', checkBoard))
});
```

```css
*{
 box-sizing:border-box;
 text-align:center;
 }
@font-face{
    font-family:BlackChancery;
    src:url(../blkChancery.ttf) format('truetype');
    }
body{
    background:teal;
    font-family:BlackChancery;
    font-size:1.17rem;  /* Nice golden yellow color 252, 186, 3 */
    }
.grid{
    margin:auto; margin-top:calc(2vh + 120px);
    border:solid 1px black; overflow:hidden;
    transform:scale(2.4); /* translate(-50%,-50%) */
    display:flex;align-content:center; justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;background-image:linear-gradient(-33deg,#384e65,#2e2e2e);
    height:124px;
    width:144px;
    }
.grid div{
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:white;
    border:solid 1.8px black;
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.44px);
    transition:all 980ms ease-in-out;
    }
.base{  /* Base set of Circles which are not used by players. */
    display:none;
    }
.player-one{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-33deg,red,rgb(186,4,119),rgb(186,4,119))!important;
    border-radius:10px;
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.34px);
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transition:all 980ms ease-in-out;
    }
.player-two{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-33deg,blue,rgb(4,186,156),rgb(4,186,156))!important;
    border-radius:10px;
    filter:hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.34px);
    transform:rotate(0deg);
    transition:all 980ms ease-in-out;
    }
.player-one:hover{
    filter:hue-rotate(-49deg) blur(0.34px);
    transform:rotate(54deg);
    transition:all 980ms ease-in-out;
    }

.player-two:hover{
    filter:hue-rotate(47deg) blur(0.34px);
    transform:rotate(54deg);
    transition:all 980ms ease-in-out;
    }
#current-player{
    position:relative;
    background-image:linear-gradient(-33deg,red,rgb(186,4,119),rgb(186,4,119))!important;
    filter:blur(0.588px); text-shadow:1px 1px 1.7px white;
    border:solid 2.98px black;
    width:148px !important;
    height:48px !important;
    font-size:1.94rem;
    border-radius:50%;
    padding:8px 28px;
    margin-top:8px;
    top:8px;
    }
#Reset{
    margin-top:calc(1.8vh + 78px);
    padding:4px 8px 4px 8px;
    border-radius:7px;
    background:rgb(67, 240, 211);
    font-size:1.24rem;
    }

    /* position:absolute;
    top:50vh; left:50vw; */
```

```html
    <h1>Custom Connect Four<br>2 player Game</h1>
    <h3>The Current Player<br>is: Player <br><span id="current-player" width="50">1</span></h3>
    <h3 id="result"></h3>

    <div class="grid">
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>
        <div></div><div></div><div></div><div></div>

        <div></div>
        <div></div>

        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
        <div class="taken base"></div>
    </div><br>

    <button id="Reset">Reset</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js" integrity="sha256-hBMojZuWKocCflyaG8T19KBq9OlTlK39CTxb8AUWKhY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Are there any errors that I've not spotted?
How could it be improved? Styling could be a lot better I guess,
but any other suggestions apart from that?

In the codepen example i have switched out all the let & const statements & created a helper function for document.querySelector & selectorAll..

Answer (score 3):

**Use the `defer` attribute** on the script tag instead of having a `DOMContentLoaded` listener - it'll cut down on a level of indentation throughout your *entire* script.

**Use `let` instead of an IIFE** to solve the closure-inside-loops issue - `let` is block-scoped to each iteration inside the loop out-of-the box, so there's no need for an IIFE - it significantly reduces the noisyness of the code. If you need to support IE11, then like always, the tried-and-true professional solution is to write code in the latest version of the language, keeping the source code as readable and elegant as possible, and then use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile down to ES5 automatically for production. (Don't transpile to ES5 manually!)

Another option would be to consider using **event delegation** instead of adding a listener to each cell: watch for clicks on the whole `.grid`, and when a cell is clicked, get the target child's index from the collection of children inside the click listener.

**Save the clicked square in a variable** instead of repeating `squares[index]` lots of times - write [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.

**`base` elements are weird** - you have 7 `<div class="taken base"></div>` elements at the end presumably in order for the `squares[index + 7].classList.contains('taken')` test to work. These `taken base` elements are always hidden - they exist solely for this logic. Consider removing them entirely, and instead checking to see if `squares[index + 7]` exists first:

```
const belowSquare = squares[index + 7];
if(!belowSquare || belowSquare.classList.contains('taken')){
```

**Enter short branches first** so you can return early without requiring many `}`s at the end of a long block - it makes the logic easier to follow when a reader of the code doesn't have to keep track of a condition that was used 20 lines ago.

```
if (belowSquare && !belowSquare.classList.contains('taken')) {
  alert('Cant Go Here')
  return;
}
// rest of the code
```

**Avoid `alert`** and its siblings `confirm` and `prompt` - they're not user-friendly, since they block the browser; when one of those dialogs is active, other JavaScript and page painting will not occur, and the page will seem completely unresponsive until the dialog is dismissed. Better to make a proper modal in the DOM and insert text into it instead.

**Grammar** Proper spelling and grammer really helps improve the presentation of an app. Use `"Can't go here"`.

**DRY circle toggling** Rather than two separate branches for each possible player, make the `player-#` class use a number for the player rather than words, so that setting the active player just requires concatenation with the `currentPlayer`:

```
square.classList.add('taken');
square.classList.add('player-' + currentPlayer);
currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;
```

**Only use `innerHTML` when deliberately inserting HTML markup** - otherwise, `textContent` is faster, safer, and more appropriate.

**Don't add the same listener to an element lots of times in a loop** with `resetBtn`, since the logic to carry out is the same - instead, add a *single* listener to the button, and inside the listener, iterate over all elements necessary. Also, there's no need to declare parameters you don't use: `(e) =>` can be `() =>`. Lastly, to reset all the class names of an element, you can assign the empty string to its `className`.

```
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (const square of squares) {
    square.className = '';
  }
  displayCurrentPlayer.textContent = 1;
});
```

**Use precise, descriptive function names** to make the code more self-documenting, and to avoid the need for comments. This:

```
//check the board for a win or lose
function checkBoard() {
```

can be

```
checkBoardForWinner() {
```

Also, rather than adding a click listener to each square that calls this, call this *inside the listener* already on each square.

**`winningArrays` is WET and buggy** There are many 4-in-a-row combinations it doesn't pick up on. For example:

[image]

A better approach would be to encode the 4-in-a-row logic dynamically based in the indicies. Iterate over all cells, and check whether the northeast, east, southeast, or south have 3 of the same squares in a row. See `checkBoardForWinner` below:

```js
const displayCurrentPlayer = document.querySelector('#current-player');
const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.grid div');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('#Reset');
const result = document.querySelector('#result');

let currentPlayer = 1;

for (let i = 0, len = squares.length; i < len; i++) {
  const square = squares[i];
  square.onclick = () => {
    // if the square below your current square is taken, you can go on top of it.
    const belowSquare = squares[i + 7];
    if (belowSquare && !belowSquare.classList.contains('taken')) {
      alert("Can't go here");
      return;
    }
    square.classList.add('taken');
    square.classList.add('player-' + currentPlayer);
    currentPlayer = currentPlayer === 1 ? 2 : 1;
    displayCurrentPlayer.textContent = currentPlayer;
    checkBoardForWinner();
  };
}
resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (const square of squares) {
    square.className = '';
  }
  displayCurrentPlayer.textContent = 1;
});
const getPlayerOnSquare = square => {
  if (!square) return null;
  const { classList } = square;
  return classList.contains('player-1')
    ? 1
    : classList.contains('player-2')
      ? 2
      : null;
};
function checkBoardForWinner() {
  for (let baseSquareIndex = 0; baseSquareIndex < squares.length; baseSquareIndex++) {
    const directionIndexDifferences = [
      -6, // Northeast
      1, // East
      8, // Southeast
      7 // South
    ];
    // Look 4 squares in each direction from baseSquareIndex
    // If each of those squares has the same player, they win
    const playersOnSquares = directionIndexDifferences.map(
      difference => Array.from(
        { length: 4 },
        (_, i) => getPlayerOnSquare(squares[baseSquareIndex + (i * difference)])
      )
    );
    const foundSequence = playersOnSquares.find(
      players => players[0] && players.every(player => player === players[0])
    );
    if (foundSequence) {
      result.textContent = `Player ${foundSequence[0]} wins!`;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: BlackChancery;
  src: url(../blkChancery.ttf) format('truetype');
}

body {
  background: teal;
  font-family: BlackChancery;
  font-size: 1.17rem;
  /* Nice golden yellow color 252, 186, 3 */
}

.grid {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: calc(2vh + 120px);
  border: solid 1px black;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: scale(2.4);
  /* translate(-50%,-50%) */
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-33deg, #384e65, #2e2e2e);
  height: 124px;
  width: 144px;
}

.grid div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: white;
  border: solid 1.8px black;
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.44px);
  transition: all 980ms ease-in-out;
}

.player-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-33deg, red, rgb(186, 4, 119), rgb(186, 4, 119))!important;
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.34px);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 980ms ease-in-out;
}

.player-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(-33deg, blue, rgb(4, 186, 156), rgb(4, 186, 156))!important;
  border-radius: 10px;
  filter: hue-rotate(0deg) blur(0.34px);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 980ms ease-in-out;
}

.player-one:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(-49deg) blur(0.34px);
  transform: rotate(54deg);
  transition: all 980ms ease-in-out;
}

.player-two:hover {
  filter: hue-rotate(47deg) blur(0.34px);
  transform: rotate(54deg);
  transition: all 980ms ease-in-out;
}

#current-player {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-33deg, red, rgb(186, 4, 119), rgb(186, 4, 119))!important;
  filter: blur(0.588px);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1.7px white;
  border: solid 2.98px black;
  width: 148px !important;
  height: 48px !important;
  font-size: 1.94rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 8px 28px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  top: 8px;
}

#Reset {
  margin-top: calc(1.8vh + 78px);
  padding: 4px 8px 4px 8px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  background: rgb(67, 240, 211);
  font-size: 1.24rem;
}


/* position:absolute;
    top:50vh; left:50vw; */
```

```html
<h1>Custom Connect Four<br>2 player Game</h1>
<h3>The Current Player<br>is: Player <br><span id="current-player" width="50">1</span></h3>
<h3 id="result"></h3>

<div class="grid">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>

  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div><br>

<button id="Reset">Reset</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/3.2.0/anime.min.js" integrity="sha256-hBMojZuWKocCflyaG8T19KBq9OlTlK39CTxb8AUWKhY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```